# Can't compare two floating number in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is:

```
function checking(data,ans,no){

    var results = data.split(','),i;
    ans = parseFloat(Math.round(ans* 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    alert('correct : ' + results[--no]);
        alert('my ans: ' + ans);
        var correct = parseFloat(results[--no]);
        var givenAns = parseFloat(ans);
        var diff = correct - givenAns;
        alert(diff);
    if(correct == givenAns){
    alert('correct');
      $('#wrong'+ no).hide();
      $('#ok'+ no).show();
      setTimeout(function() { return true; }, 1500);
    }
    else{
    alert('not correct');
      $('#ok'+ no).hide();
      $('#wrong'+ no).show();
      var temp = no+1;
      $('#notSolveBtn'+ temp).show();
      return false;
    }

}

function check_ans(ans,no){
    $.get('AnswerSheet/1.txt', function(data) {
          checking(data,ans,no)
    }, 'text');
}
```

**Problem:**

```
alert('correct : ' + results[--no]);
            alert('my ans: ' + ans);
```

this two lines alert 
correct : 115.38
my ans : 115.38
But  ans == results[--no] always return false. Again I parse these two values into float type if there is any type mismatch issue. Still same problem. To be confirmed I subtract one from another:

```
 var diff = correct - givenAns;
            alert(diff);
```

but `alert(diff);` alert NAN which should alert 0.00 or 0. Whats wrong am I doing. Sorry if this problem already asked. I googled a lot of time but no luck.

Comment: can you post what you get in data

Comment: I only see a parsing of ans and not of result. In particular, when using ´split´, the results are string (array of strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is you only parse `ans` and not result so add this here

```
resultFloat = parseFloat(result[no]).toFixed(2);
```

Second, I wouldn't use `--no` if you are not 100% certain of what you are doing. In your code you compare two different things, in the first `alert` you had a different entry of the array than in the parting `var correct = ...`. So better just define the new `no` at one point and use that value for the following usage

```
function checking(data,ans,no){

    var results = data.split(','),i;
    no--;
    resultFloat = parseFloat(result[no]).toFixed(2);
    ans = parseFloat(Math.round(ans* 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    alert('correct : ' + resultFloat); // <-- this one and...
        alert('my ans: ' + ans);
        var correct = resultFloat; // <-- ...this one were different before, was that on purpose?
        var givenAns = ans;
        var diff = correct - givenAns;
        alert(diff);
....
```

Comment: Thanks @RobertStettler. it will help future too.